# scrollTopTop listener not working in component (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I used to have the same implementation in ScrollView and it was working and when I changed to flatlist my scroll to top stopped working

I am using an event register, since I have nested navigation.

Here is my implementation:
(in Navigation.js)

```
<Tab.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeNavigation}
  listeners={({navigation, route}) => ({
    tabPress: () => {
      const isAtFirstScreenOfStack =
        !route.state || route.state?.index === 0;
      if (navigation.isFocused() && isAtFirstScreenOfStack) {
        console.log('Scrolling to Top');
        EventRegister.emit('scrollToTop', 'it works!!!');
      }
    },
  })}
```

in the component where I have the list:

```
let scrollViewRef = useRef(null);
let scrollToTopListener = useRef(null);

useFocusEffect(
useCallback(() => {
  scrollToTopListener.current = EventRegister.addEventListener(
    'scrollToTop',
    () => {
      if (scrollViewRef.current) {
        scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({y: 0, animated: true});
      }
    },
  );

  return () => {
    EventRegister.removeEventListener(scrollToTopListener.current);
  };
}, []),
```

);

```
 ...
   <FlatList
     ref={(ref) => (scrollViewRef = ref)}
     ...
```

Comment: <FlatList
       
          ref={scrollViewRef}

try to register your ref like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scrollToOffset in FlatList

```
ref.current.scrollToOffset({y:0,animated:true})
```

Comment: Still not working, my `scrollViewRef` is always null. Am I referencing it wrong ?

Comment: I do it like ref={scrollViewRef}

Comment: Thank you, `scrollToOffset` with `ref={scrollViewRef}` worked for me